# bash unbind CTRL-W (bash 4.1 solaris 11.3)

Tags: bash, key-binding

I've looked through multiple old posts, but nothing is working.

I've made the following changes to no avail:

```
#file: .inputrc

    set bind-tty-special-chars off #I have a cursory understanding of what this does, I really want to disable all mappings so I can build them from scratch myself


#file: .bashrc
    stty werase undef #again, just script kittying my way through this, no idea if this should be needed given that .inputrc has set bind-tty-special-chars off 
    bind -r "\C-w" #hoping this will unmap CTRL-W from all functions?
    bind -q unix-word-rubout #hoping this will remove unix-word-rubout functionality?
```

fwiw, stty does not exist in any startup file except in a comment or already mentioned above:
grep stty .*
.bashrc:stty werase undef
.profile:#stty erase ^H

I use SecureCRT to connect, and while I've done some mapping there, it has no mapping for CTRL-W
, when I press CTRL-V CTRL-W, i get:
^W

Can anyone please guide me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was .bashrc only runs if I manually run bash, it only executes on interactive non-login :(

Adding those same commands to .profile did the trick